# How to stop prettyNum from converting my one row dataframe to a character vector

Tags: r, dataframe, implicit-conversion, xtable

I am using `prettyNum` in combination with `xtable` to produce nice LaTeX tables. It works as expected when I have more than one row in the `data.frame`. But when I only have one row it fails because `prettyNum` converts the `data.frame` to a character vector.

Is there a simple way similar to "`drop = FALSE`" to retain a `data.frame` from `prettyNum`?

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1, b ='a')
prettyDf <- prettyNum(df) 
class(prettyDf)
[1] "character"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two basic options you can use: convert the output to a one-row matrix before using `xtable`, or you can use `apply` to convert to `prettyNum`.

Here is a minimal example:

First, some sample data. A one row `data.frame` and a three row `data.frame`:

```
df <- structure(
  list(V1 = 76491283764.9743, V2 = 29.12345678901, V3 = -7.1234, V4 = -100.1, 
       V5 = 1123), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"), 
  row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame")
df
#            V1       V2      V3     V4   V5
# 1 76491283765 29.12346 -7.1234 -100.1 1123

df2 <- rbind(df, df*2, df*3)
df2
#             V1       V2       V3     V4   V5
# 1  76491283765 29.12346  -7.1234 -100.1 1123
# 2 152982567530 58.24691 -14.2468 -200.2 2246
# 3 229473851295 87.37037 -21.3702 -300.3 3369
```

Using `xtable` on the 3-row one works fine, ***but unlike what you stated in your question, it does not retain a `data.frame`. It converts the output to a character matrix.***:

```
> class(prettyNum(df2, big.mark=","))
[1] "matrix"

> xtable(prettyNum(df2, big.mark=","), align = "rrrrrr")
% latex table generated in R 2.15.3 by xtable 1.7-1 package
% Fri Mar 22 15:46:08 2013
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrr}
  \hline
 & V1 & V2 & V3 & V4 & V5 \\ 
  \hline
1 &  76,491,283,765 &        29.12346 &         -7.1234 &          -100.1 &           1,123 \\ 
  2 & 152,982,567,530 &        58.24691 &        -14.2468 &          -200.2 &           2,246 \\ 
  3 & 229,473,851,295 &        87.37037 &        -21.3702 &          -300.3 &           3,369 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Trying the same on the 1-row data.frame gives us an error, because in the process of "prettifying" your numbers, the data.frame becomes a named character vector, as you already figured out:

```
> xtable(prettyNum(df, big.mark = ","), align = "rrrrrr")
Error in UseMethod("xtable") : 
  no applicable method for 'xtable' applied to an object of class "character"
```

Use `methods(xtable)` to see the types of objects for which `xtable` methods have been defined. To view a specific method--for example, the `xtable.data.frame` method--use `xtable:::xtable.data.frame`. From there, you can learn how to write your own method if you think it's necessary.

However, in this case, it's not necessary. Just try one of the following options, noting the subtle difference between the them:

```
xtable(matrix(prettyNum(df, big.mark = ","), nrow = 1), align = "rrrrrr")
xtable(t(apply(df, 1, prettyNum, big.mark = ",")), align = "rrrrrr")
```

Here is some sample output:

[image]